# Portable compile parameters of a Jamfile

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-build, bjam

Here is a Jamfile that I currently use to build a test.

```
exe file_test
        : file_test.cpp ../src/file.hpp ../src//file
        : <cxxflags>--std=c++11
        : <linkflags>-ltag
        ;
```

Is there any way to switch to c++11 standard without being gcc specific? And is there any portable possibility to give bjam the link flags (or is this a portable way?)? I know that I can write conditional parameters but that would mean that I have to write the parameters for any compiler I would like to support. Thus I hope that bjam has a solution for this.

Additionally I would like to know if there is a meaning in not deleting the "bin" directory after calling "bjam clean".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537786/boost-bjam-link-result-with-precompiled-library) for external libraries.
Unfortunately, library names are sometimes platform specifc as well (.a/.lib) so I

As for compiler flags, if it is not part of the [built-in features](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/bbv2/overview.html#bbv2.overview.invocation.properties), you would have to add support yourself for each toolset, which is probably even more work.

I had to maintain bjam for a build system at work and I must say, if something does not come in-the-box with it, it can be really hard to find help elsewhere.

Comment: Well, I realised that bjam is not very convenient if I have specific wishes. Therefore I didn't use it anymore.